Motto help for an all-risk emergency air crew..."so/that California may know", future subjunctive?
This is for a state funded intel aircraft crew that flies fire, flood, and earthquake for real-time maps and livestream. We are considering a phrase similar to USAF pararescue "That others may live". We've chosen "So California may know" or "That California may know".
Amateur research and study have led me towards a couple of phrases: Ut California noscent...or Sic California sciant. Would anyone know if either is correct, better in context of the mission, or even close?
We appreciate any assistance!

Latin does, in fact, not have a future subjunctive. There are ways to construct a replacement (using the so-called periphrastic conjugation), as in the famous quid sit futurum cras, fuge quaerere (do not ask what will happen tomorrow, Horace Carm. 1, 9); however, this is unnecessary in your case, where the future sense is already expressed by a present subjunctive.
In ut California noscent, you are using the future tense, necessarily indicative. Ut does indeed mean “so that,” but in this sense it requires a subjunctive, so that is not grammatical. (Even more problematic, noscent is plural.)
In sic California sciat, you are using the present subjunctive correctly, but sic means “in this way,” so the meaning is not really what you want to express. (In English, “so” is an amazingly versatile word, so what would be a good Latin equivalent in one case might be completely wrong in another. Sic is often used for “so,” but not here.)
My suggestion, therefore, would be ut California sciat. If you prefer the verb noscere, things are a little more complicated, as this verb tends to use perfect forms for present meanings; however, it means “know” more in the sense of “be acquainted with,” whereas scire is obviously associated with “science,” so I believe the latter is a better fit for your purpose.

Thank you Sebastian. This is very helpful. I have been asked to use a different subject...like citizen, people or community instead of "California". So, could it be as simple as "that citizens may know" becomes "ut civis/civitas sciant"? Or, less exclusive and "ut plebes sciant"?
I'm afraid that my education in Spanish and French is oversimplifying my approach to this rich and wonderful language.
Vielen dank Herr Koppehel!
